# object oriented javascript form registeration

Tags: javascript

i am new to the object oriented javascript :)
i have written this code to validate the first name of a registration form, but it is not working

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>OOForm</title>
        <meta name="author" content="engy" />
        <!-- Date: 2015-02-20 -->
        <script>
        var Form = {
            fname:{
                minLength : 1,
                maxLength : 15,
            },
            validateLength:function(formEl,type){
                if(formEl.value.length>type.maxLength||formEl.value.length<type.minLength){
                    document.getElementById("firstNameSpan").innerHTML = "<font color='red'>Invalid User Name</font>";
                    return false;
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("firstNameSpan").innerHTML = "";
                    return true;
                }
            },
        };

        function checkForm(){
            var ourForm = document.getElementById("ourForm");
            var inputs = ourForm.getElementsByTagName("input");
            if(Form.validateLength(inputs[0],Form.fname)){
                    document.getElementById("mySubmit").disabled = false;
                    return true;
                }

        document.getElementById("mySubmit").disabled = true;
        return false;
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="ourForm">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text"/>
            <span id="firstNameSpan"> </span>
            <br/>

            <input type="submit" value="submit" id="mySubmit" onclick="return checkForm()">
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

i don't know what is the problem with the code, but when i enter the firstname with invalid value and then press submit, it do nothing but clearing the text field
and the "invalid" span do not appear

Comment: Two things: it is `getElementsByTagName` with an s and you have not defined what `submit_button` is. Give the submit button an `id` and get access to it using `getElementById`

Comment: i did what you said, but it still not working
i gave an id to the button and used the getElementById and modified getElementsByTagName, but still not working
 i have edited the post, you can see the changes

Comment: yes, check the edited post, it is changed :)

Comment: You have not changed this: `var inputs = ourForm.getElementByTagName("input");` There should be an `s` there

Comment: Just curious, what is "object-oriented JavaScript"? Is it different from regular old JavaScript? If I write `var foo = {};`, that's an object, so is my program now object-oriented? If I write `var foo = { f: function() { } };` that's a method on an object, so it my program now object-oriented JavaScript?

Comment: i modified it in my program, but forgot editing it here, but i have changed it too and nothing happened

Comment: @tarazaburo:  see this, it may help :)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you need to do onsubmit on form element instead of onclick and you need to return false in onsubmit so browser won't try to send your form.